# Using Order By Desc on Datetime2 Format DB2

Tags: sql, db2, row-number

I am creating a cte with a partition that orders datetime2 stamps in descending count and applying row_number(), and then selecting row 1 to get the most recent date.

```
with cte1 as 
(
select Customer_Number, event, Source_update_date, row_number() over
(partition by Customer_Number order by Source_update_date desc) row_num
from schema.table
where event = ''ACTIVE''
)
select Customer_Number, event
from cte1
where row_num = 1
```

I notice that the most recent date is selected, but not the largest .nnnnnnn part. how to account for this? its a DB2 server

the two dates in question are:

2018-03-27 09:22:52.0000230

2018-03-27 09:21:16.0000210 (this one is being selected as the top even though 210 is less than 230)

Comment: That's really worrisome since the minutes & seconds are different before you get to .nnnnnnn. and clearly 22 > 21... so I would expect the 1st record to be selected...  Are you sure they have the same customer number and are not part of different partitions (think non-display characters may be involved)?

Comment: xQbert you were absolutely right, I reviewed my where statement and I had a line in there which would have removed the row for 2018-03-27 09:22:52.0000230 which is why 2018-03-27 09:21:16.0000210 was selected, it was the most recent one left over. Well since you answered my question put this as an answer and ill give you props! thanks

Comment: To me it sounds like you eliminated that record and found your own answer; `hey if I want the earliest source_update_Date, I shouldn't exclude it...` Post it and accept it!  I just was thinking it was in a different partition; not that a where clause eliminated the value.  I don't need the props, just happy to help :P

Comment: props anyway, I didn't notice the minutes and seconds were different which caused me to look at the where statement more closely (its been a long day)

Comment: It happens.  You answered your own question. I just provided a different line of thinking to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reviewing my where statement I noticed that 2018-03-27 09:22:52.0000230 was being excluded, an alteration to the where statement is now producing correct results in the above query. I removed where event = ACTIVE since I realized sometimes the most recent event is CLOSE which was the case in the above customer_number.